# Ruby on Rails 3, unexplainable "Route doesn't match"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm facing a problem that i can't explain :/

I have created a route for a specific action.
And it shows up into `rake routes` result :

```
update_attendance_admin_module_instance_activity_instance_list
POST
/admin/module_instances/:module_instance_id/activity_instances/:activity_instance_id/lists/:id/update_attendance(.:format)
{:action=>"update_attendance", :controller=>"admin/lists"}
```

This action si suppose to handle a form submission :

```
= form_for @upload, :url => {:controller => 'admin/lists', :action => 'update_attendance', :id => @upload.id}
```

BTW : I also tried to use the helper `update_attendance_admin_module_instance_activity_instance_list_path` but it's very wordy and doesn't work either.

Then when the form is submitted :

```
Started POST "/admin/module_instances/2/activity_instances/2/lists/1/update_attendance" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-11-11 11:16:48 +0100

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/admin/module_instances/2/activity_instances/2/lists/1/update_attendance"):
```

A url successfully generated through a path helper is supposed to match and rails should fail generate the view if the route wasn't matching...

So, my question is simple : **Why this route doesn't match ?**

Hopefully some one will see something obvious (and probably stupid) otherwise i will need some xanax :D

Thanks for your help :p

PS : [routes.rb file available here](http://odeoos.com/downloads/routes.rb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok when using an update action (object gave to form_for not empty). The method must be PUT instead of POST.

The weird part is : why Rails didn't displays this message ?

```
Started PUT "/admin/module_instances/2/activity_instances/2/lists/1/update_attendance"
```

Instead of this one

```
Started POST "/admin/module_instances/2/activity_instances/2/lists/1/update_attendance"
```

At the end the solution is simple in the route file :

Replace that :

```
post :update_attendance
```

by that :

```
put :update_attendance
```